# BEA / Oracle Aqualogic BPM question

Tags: session, timeout, business-process-management, bea, albpm

I'm using BEA Aqualogic BPM 5.7 and after a while I'm getting the time out screen.
It says BEA Aqualogic Hiper WorkSpace for BPM, your session has expired and it has a "Login again" button.

Does anybody know how to change that screen or how to increase the time out so the user does not see that screen so often?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the http session-timeout in `$ALBPM_HOME/webapps/portal/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

This sets the session timeout to 20 minutes.

PS: for ALBPM 6.0, have a look at [this document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12483_01/albsi60/workspace_customization/index.html?t=workspace_customization/r_WorkSpace_Config_File_Reference.html) (but I'm not sure it applies to 5.7).